# WPF: Binding Grid.Visibility OneWay to a dependency property and OneWayToSource to a view model CLR property

Tags: wpf, dependency-properties, multibinding, attached-properties, isoneway

I have a *Grid* to which the **Visibility** property is bound to **IsExpanded** of a parent *Expander* control.

Whenever **Grid.Visibility** changes, I want a property (**MyProperty**) on the **DataContext** (the view model) to change accordingly.

This is my XAML:

```
<Grid Visibility="{Binding IsExpanded, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Expander}}, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}}" />
```

I have tried programmatically setting the binding in the view constructor using:

```
grid.SetBinding(VisibilityProperty, new Binding("MyProperty") { Source = DataContext });
```

However, this just replaces the binding to the *Expander* already set in the XAML.

I considered flipping this around so that the target is my view model and the source is the grid instead (binding to **Visibility**) and making **MyProperty** into a dependency property. But, my view model is not a *DependencyObject*, so I cannot do this.

I have tried using a *MultiBinding* / *MultiConverter* binding **Grid.Visibility** to **Expander.IsExpanded** and **MyProperty**, but this doesn't have the desired effect. **MyProperty** doesn't get changed to **Grid.Visibility** when **Grid.Visibility** is updated as a result of **Expander.IsExpanded** changing.

The only option that seems to work is using an attached property on *Grid* which binds to **Expander.IsExpanded** and then use a callback function to programmatically change **Grid.Visibility** whenever the attached property changes. **Grid.Visibility** then binds to **MyProperty**. This just seems like a messy way of doing it, but I am open to suggestions.

I guess what I'm trying to do is almost like a two-pronged binding where the two bindings are in opposite directions, one being *from* a dependency property, the other being *to* a CLR property.

Thanks for any help that can be given!!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can set visibility of grid with triggers on Expanders and bind grid.Visibility to your ViewModel. This approach is similar to your solution with code behind but with triggers instead of code.

In my opinion your solution with code behind is good enough too. Who said that everything has to be in XAML not code-behind. Code-behind is usually bad for business logic and such but it is completely Ok to have visual logic in code-behind if it can't be expressed in XAML only.

Comment: Setting **Grid.Visibility** from a _DataTrigger_ on the containing _Expander_ is not suitable as this would mean the _Expander_ would have to be aware of the child _Grid_. The point of using a **FindAncestor** binding is where you want an element to react to a parent element without the parent having to know about the child. _Expander_ is part of a _UserControl_ that has a _ContentPresenter_ which may not have a _Grid_ in it.

My programmatic solution doesn't fix my problem because, as I mentioned, it just replaces the binding to the _Expander_ already set in the XAML; it doesn't aggregate it.